# How to delay a script without delaying blender's startup?

Tags: python, scripting, shortcut

I placed a script in blender's startup scripts folder so that it runs automatically. However, I need it to run after blender starts up or else it throws out an error.

How can I delay or keep trying to run my script without delaying the blender startup routine?

Comment: I would suggest focusing the question (and title) on the keymap error and not the idea of delaying startup. See the XY problem: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: I understand, I just felt the keymap error would provide valuable context to anyone that could help me, but if the rules are against the structure I used then I will remove it.

Comment: It's not a rule, just a suggestion. Having said that, you have in fact done the *opposite* of what I suggested, which was to focus the question on the keymap issue, *not* delaying when a script starts (which, if it would even work, seems like a 'hacky' workaround and not a real/good solution).

Comment: I want to thank you for your suggestion but what you wanted was not what I wanted. You're right though, the title now matches the issue I want to address; there should be no confusion now. Not that it matters anyway, I already found the code i needed. I know my hacky solution is beneath you but for someone like me who doesn't know coding it's all I have. P.S. It's working beautifully!

Comment: If you have a solution, please post it in the answer box below.

Comment: I don't think I should, it's not a real/good solution and it's hacky.